# why the connect/token endpoint doesn't validate the refresh token when it refresh the access token in identityServer4

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

why the connect/token endpoint doesn't validate the refresh token when it refresh the access token in identityServer4

I have two website, one is the mvc ,another is identity server.
after I login in mvc,get the access token and refresh token. after 10 mins,the access token was expired. I delete the refresh token in the database and restart the identity server .when I access the api which is required authorize,the browser redirect to the identity server connect/authorize endpoint. for a while ,the browser redirect to mvc ,means the client get the access token and I saw the new refresh token generate in the database.

I have saw the source code ,but i can't find any validate in the endpoint.is true?

Comment: This is because the IdentityServer cookie still exists, thus you are still logged in. So you just triggered another SSO login. If you'd like to test this the way you want, you also need to delete IdentityServer cookies.

Comment: yes,the cookies still exists. but the mvc client validate the cookies, it was expired. so the website call the IdentityServer to refresh the access_token. if I delete the cookies, it will redrect to the login page, doesn't refresh the access_token. I though it is the difference